# how to get text from a WebPage that disappear when loaded. C#, HTML-Agility-Pack

Tags: c#, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to make a programme that load bunch of sites and get specific information and display it in the console. One of the pages is steam trading card this link for example https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/753/433340-Pink%20Slime, as u can see if u entered that steam market place there is numbers that describe how much the item is for sale or to buy. when I'm trying to get that info from HTML-Agility-pack in C#. i get no information. i loaded the `htmlweb` with this code: `Console.WriteLine(htmldoc.Text);`
in visual studio code, i found that the price is empty. asking if anyone know how to acces that information.

Comment: It is because the price is not in the source it is loaded from a URL like this `https://steamcommunity.com/market/itemordershistogram?country=US&language=english&currency=1&item_nameid=147920970&two_factor=0`

Comment: @Eldar thnx a lot a lot i was stuck for a long time figuring out how to get it. but though can u tell me how u got that source?

Comment: @Eldar btw i found a solution how to get that link from code but i still have the same probleme when i try to access that link from HTML-agility-pack.. i just get null here what ive done
```var htmldoc2 = web.Load(PriceUrlForCurrentCardUrl);
Console.WriteLine("___> ", htmldoc2.Text);
```

Comment: I found it from the network panel from the developer tools of chrome. All you need to find is some element that contains `tem_nameid=147920970`

Comment: @Eldar thnx again but can u explain to me why i cant eccess that info from that link from html agility pack. when i try to load it, it just give"s me "" emptyness

Comment: Because it is rendered asynchronously by the javascript, you either need to change your tech stack to use something puppeteer, playwright, or selenium headless browsers, or you can stick with this approach. Still, you will need two requests to accomplish what you need. By the way, headless browsers will try to load everything the page requires (CSS, vendor js, images) optimizing them will be tough work.